# Simple url mod_rewrite .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I want to change the url from:

```
http://sitename.com/?game=runescape
```

to

```
http://sitename.com/game/runescape
```

I use $_GET['game'] to request the slug and retrieve data from the database.
Does anyone know if this is possible and how?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried? What did you already search for? There are LOADS of tutorials about this all over

Comment: You want someting like var/value translated in var=value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: Yes, I've tried every tutorial out here, but most of them use a different page to access the content like sitename.com/game.php?=runescape

Comment: And Yes! I want something like 'var/value' translated from 'var=value'

Answer (score 2):

This rule should work for any `game`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/game/(.+?)$ index.php?game=$1
```